# jQuery's $.post method AJAX is not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Lately I've been experimenting with AJAX and jQuery. But somehow $.post method doesn't seem to work. Anybody got solutions?

Here's my code.

```
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function send(){
      $.post('t.php', {stuff:1}, function(data){
        if(data == 'success'){
          alert('works');
       } 
      });
 }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="btn" onclick="send()">CLICK</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my `t.php`:

`<?php echo "success";?>`

Comment: *Doesn't seem to work* is very vague and doesn't really give us anything to work with. What happens? What did you expect? Have you tried debugging to see if the request is actually sent? Are there any error messages?

Comment: This was to test if the $.post method worked , if it did it would have alerted 'works'..i just dont know where the problem is and there are no errors.

Comment: The post method works just fine, try debugging it. The crux is that you don't get data back in the way you expect.

Comment: try console.log(data) first. to check what is getting the event.

Comment: it should be a button instead of div <input id="btn" type="button" value="submit" onclick="send()"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works actually but you don't know that how to get response from `php` file properly

Change ajax code like below:

```
$.post('t.php', {stuff:1}, function(data){
    if(data[0] == 's'){//changed here. data is an array not string
      alert('works');
   } 
  });
```

And in php

```
<?php echo "s";?>
```